# php не могу передать параметр в запрос

Tags: mysqli, preparedstatement

**sets.php**

```
$rowsOnPage=50;
```

**ajax.php**

```
require_once("sets.php");


function tableContent($tbl,$orderby="id", $orderdir="asc",$page=1){
        global $mysqlipdo, $rowsOnPage;
        $prep=$mysqlipdo->prepare("select * from $tbl order by $orderby $orderdir limit ?,?");
        $prep->bind_param("ii",(($page-1)*$rowsOnPage),$rowsOnPage);
    }
```

`Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in`

ошибка в этой строке
`$prep->bind_param("ii",(($page-1)*$rowsOnPage),$rowsOnPage)`

как правильно передать параметр?

Answer (score 0):

В **bind_param** нужно передавать переменную

Попробуйте так:

```
require_once("sets.php");


function tableContent($tbl,$orderby="id", $orderdir="asc",$page=1){
        global $mysqlipdo, $rowsOnPage;
        $prep=$mysqlipdo->prepare("select * from $tbl order by $orderby $orderdir limit ?,?");
        $offset = (($page - 1) * $rowsOnPage);
        $prep->bind_param("ii", $offset, $rowsOnPage);
}
```